# Chrome Extension & FCM fetching registration token

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a Chrome Extension that needs to be able to receive push notifications. An alternative would be polling the server every X seconds, but that doesn't seem like much of a good choice. For this reason I chose Firebase. The custom JWT token auth seems to be done and working. The next step is to fetch the registration token, and sending this to the server.

**The problem:**

The token seems to never be fetched:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<KEY>",
    authDomain: "<DOMAIN>",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>"
};
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var messaging = firebase.messaging(app);

function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            // Update UI
            fetchToken();
        } else {
            // no user is signed in
        }
    });
}

function fetchToken() {
    messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function() {
            messaging.getToken()
                .then(function(currentToken) {
                    if (currentToken) {
                        sendRegistrationTokenToServer(currentToken);
                    } else {
                        console.log('No token available')
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.debug('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Notification permissions denied.', err);
    });


    firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(function() {
        messaging.getToken()
            .then(function(refreshedToken) {
                sendRegistrationTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
                console.log('Token refreshed')
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token', err);
            });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initApp();

    // some other stuff
});
```

Does anyone know why the token isn't being fetched?

No network activity can be seen in the developer console (for fetching the token). Also no error is printed. I do, however, see network activity for `getAccountInfo?key=<somekey>` which carries an `idToken` with it, though I'm not certain this is a related request (response doesn't seem to return a token).

Comment: I am having the same problem. It is the `requestPermission` that is not returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot call `messaging.requestPermission()` from the background script. If the user has not allowed notifications, this call will attempt to prompt the user, which will fail silently.  What you can do is request the notifications permission somewhere else in your extension that has a UI (e.g. your options page) with:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => { ...
```

Once the user has allowed the permission you can use the [Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web), to query if you have the permission, in place of the call to `messaging.requestPermission()`.  This is a function I wrote to do this:

```
/**
 * Determine if navigator Notifications permission has been granted
 * Note: this will work from the background script of an extension,
 * unlike the other solutions
 * @see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web
 * @see https://w3c.github.io/permissions/
 * @see https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6443143280984064
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>} true if granted
 * @memberOf app.Notify
 */
hasNavigatorPermission: function() {
  return navigator.permissions.query({
    name: 'notifications',
  }).then((status) => {
    if (status.state === 'granted') {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  });
},
```

And use it like this:

```
/**
 * Get the registration token for fcm
 * @returns {Promise<token>} A registration token for fcm
 * @memberOf app.Fb
 */
getRegToken: function() {
  return app.Notify.hasNavigatorPermission().then((granted) => {
    if (!granted) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(ERROR_NOTIFICATIONS));
    }
    return _messaging.getToken();
  }).then((token) => {
    if (token) {
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    }
    return Promise.reject(new Error(ERROR_TOKEN));
  });
},
```

A couple other things to note:

Don't rely on `Notification.permission` in an extension. It does not have the correct value.

As of [Chrome 59](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6443143280984064), if you dismiss the notifications dialog too many times while developing, it will stop displaying it for a period of time. You need to clear your browser data to get it to start displaying again.